# Table cell borders disappear when document converted to PDF

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

For some reason when trying to export my table as a PDF document the borders dissapear. I don't have coding experience if anyone can fix my code for it to start showing the borders I would greatly appreciate it.

```
    <table class="MsoNormalTable" style="margin-left: 6.25pt; border-collapse: collapse; border-right: none; border-bottom: none; border-left: none; border-image: initial; border-top: 2.25pt solid black; height: 622px;" border="1" width="718" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 1;">
<td style="width: 1283.8pt; text-align: center; line-height: 30px; background-color: #1d6fbb; border-top: none; border-left: solid black 2.25pt; border-bottom: solid black 2.25pt; border-right: solid black 1.5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 30.0pt;" colspan="3" valign="top" width="1712">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin: 4.25pt 0in .0001pt 7.25pt;"><span style="font-size: 16pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: whitesmoke; mso-font-width: 95%;">BUSINESS</span><span style="font-size: 16pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: whitesmoke; letter-spacing: -.1pt;"> INFORMATION</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 3;">
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border: solid black 2.25pt; border-top: none; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 65.0pt;" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-top: .2pt;"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;"></b><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: #2f2f2f; position: relative; top: -1pt;">&nbsp; Business <span style="letter-spacing: -.1pt;">Name</span></span><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: dimgray; position: relative; top: -1pt; letter-spacing: -0.1pt;">:</span></p>
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-top: .2pt;"><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: dimgray; position: relative; top: -1pt;"><u>A</u> </span></p>
</td>
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid black 2.25pt; border-right: solid black 1.5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 65.0pt;" colspan="2" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-top: .05pt;"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;"></b><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: #2f2f2f; position: relative; top: -1pt;">&nbsp; Business </span><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: #2f2f2f; position: relative; top: -1pt; letter-spacing: -0.1pt;">DBA Name:</span></p>
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-top: .05pt;">&nbsp; <u>A</u>&nbsp; <u>A</u>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 1;">
<td style="width: 1283.8pt; border-top: none; border-left: solid black 2.25pt; border-bottom: solid black 2.25pt; border-right: solid black 1.5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 67.0pt;" colspan="3" valign="top" width="1712">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin: 4.25pt 0in .0001pt 7.25pt;"><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: #2f2f2f; mso-font-width: 95%;">Street </span><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: #2f2f2f; letter-spacing: -.1pt;">Address</span><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: dimgray; letter-spacing: -.1pt;">:</span></p>
<p>&nbsp; <u>A</u> &nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 2;">
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border: solid black 2.25pt; border-top: none; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 66.0pt;" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-left: 6.2pt;"><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: #2f2f2f; letter-spacing: -.1pt;">City:</span></p>
<p>&nbsp; <u>A</u>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid black 2.25pt; border-right: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 66.0pt;" valign="top" width="428">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-left: 8.25pt;"><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: #2f2f2f; letter-spacing: -.1pt;">State:<br><u>A</u> <br></span></p>
</td>
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid black 2.25pt; border-right: solid black 1.5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 66.0pt;" valign="top" width="428">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-left: 8.25pt;"><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: #2f2f2f; letter-spacing: -.2pt; mso-font-width: 105%;">Zip:</span></p>
<p>&nbsp; <u>11111</u>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 3;">
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border: solid black 2.25pt; border-top: none; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 65.0pt;" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-top: .2pt;"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;"></b><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: #2f2f2f; position: relative; top: -1pt;">&nbsp; Legal <span style="letter-spacing: -.1pt;">Entity</span></span><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: dimgray; position: relative; top: -1pt; letter-spacing: -0.1pt;">:</span></p>
<p>&nbsp; <u>Corporation</u>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid black 2.25pt; border-right: solid black 1.5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 65.0pt;" colspan="2" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-top: .05pt;"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;"></b><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: #2f2f2f; position: relative; top: -1pt;">&nbsp; Business </span><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: #2f2f2f; position: relative; top: -1pt; letter-spacing: -0.1pt;">Location:</span></p>
<p>&nbsp; <u>A</u>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 4; mso-yfti-lastrow: yes;">
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border-top: none; border-left: solid black 2.25pt; border-bottom: solid black 1.5pt; border-right: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 66.15pt;" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin: 2.25pt 0in .0001pt 8.25pt;"><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: #1a1a1a; mso-font-width: 95%;">Date </span><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: #2f2f2f; mso-font-width: 95%;">Business</span> <span style="font-size: 13.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: #2f2f2f; letter-spacing: -.1pt; mso-font-width: 95%;">Started:</span></p>
<p>&nbsp; <u>1111</u>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border: none; border-right: solid black 1.5pt; border-bottom: solid black 1.5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 66.15pt;" colspan="2" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin: 2.25pt 0in .0001pt 6.75pt;"><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: #2f2f2f; mso-font-width: 95%;">Federa</span><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: #050505; mso-font-width: 95%;">l </span><span style="color: #2f2f2f; font-size: 13.5pt;">State</span> <span style="color: #2f2f2f; font-size: 13.5pt;">Tax</span> <span style="color: #464646; font-size: 17.3333px; font-style: italic; letter-spacing: -0.333333px;">#</span></p>
<p>&nbsp; <u>11-1222222</u>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!--------------------------------------------------------------------TABLE2---------------------------------------------------------------->
<p class="MsoTitle">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="MsoBodyText">&nbsp;</p>
<table class="MsoNormalTable" style="margin-left: 6.25pt; margin-top: -90px; border-collapse: collapse; border-right: none; border-bottom: none; border-left: none; border-image: initial; border-top: 2.25pt solid black; height: 757px;" border="1" width="716" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 4; mso-yfti-lastrow: yes;">
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border-top: none; border-left: solid black 2.25pt; text-align: center; line-height: 60px; border-bottom: solid black 1.5pt; border-right: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 66.15pt; background-color: #1d6fbb;" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin: 2.25pt 0in .0001pt 8.25pt;"><span style="font-size: 16pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%); mso-font-width: 95%;">OWNER</span><span style="font-size: 16pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: #ffffff; mso-font-width: 95%;"> PRINCIPAL INFORMATION</span></p>
</td>
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border: none; border-right: solid black 1.5pt; border-bottom: solid black 1.5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 66.15pt; text-align: center; line-height: 60px; background-color: #1d6fbb;" colspan="2" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin: 2.25pt 0in .0001pt 6.75pt;"><span style="font-size: 16pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: whitesmoke; mso-font-width: 95%;">OWNER</span><span style="font-size: 16pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: #fffcfc; mso-font-width: 95%;"> #2 (IF APPLICABLE)</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 3; height: 65.0pt;">
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border: solid black 2.25pt; border-top: none; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 65.0pt;" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-top: .2pt;"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;"></b><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: #2f2f2f; position: relative; top: -1pt;"><span style="letter-spacing: -.1pt;"> Name:<br><u>A</u></span></span></p>
</td>
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid black 2.25pt; border-right: solid black 1.5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 65.0pt;" colspan="2" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-top: .05pt;"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;"></b><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: #2f2f2f; position: relative; top: -1pt; letter-spacing: -0.1pt;"> <span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: #2f2f2f; position: relative; top: -1pt;"><span style="letter-spacing: -.1pt;">Name:<br></span></span></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 2; height: 66.0pt;">
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border: solid black 2.25pt; border-top: none; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 66.0pt;" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-left: 6.2pt;">Address:<br><u>A</u></p>
</td>
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid black 2.25pt; border-right: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 66.0pt;" valign="top" width="428">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-left: 8.25pt;"><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt; color: #2f2f2f; letter-spacing: -.1pt;">Address:<br> <br></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 3; height: 65.0pt;">
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border: solid black 2.25pt; border-top: none; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 65.0pt;" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-top: .2pt;"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;"></b><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: #2f2f2f; position: relative; top: -1pt;">&nbsp; City, <span style="letter-spacing: -.1pt;">State, Zip:</span></span></p>
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-top: .2pt;"><u>A</u> , <u>A</u> , <u>11111</u>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid black 2.25pt; border-right: solid black 1.5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 65.0pt;" colspan="2" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-top: .05pt;"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;"></b><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: #2f2f2f; position: relative; top: -1pt;">&nbsp; City, </span><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: #2f2f2f; position: relative; top: -1pt; letter-spacing: -0.1pt;">State, Zip:</span></p>
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin-top: .05pt;"> ,  , &nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 4; mso-yfti-lastrow: yes; height: 66.15pt;">
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border-top: none; border-left: solid black 2.25pt; border-bottom: solid black 1.5pt; border-right: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 66.15pt;" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin: 2.25pt 0in .0001pt 8.25pt;"><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: #2f2f2f; position: relative; top: -1pt;"><span style="letter-spacing: -.1pt;">SSN#:<br><u>111-11-1111</u></span></span></p>
</td>
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border: none; border-right: solid black 1.5pt; border-bottom: solid black 1.5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 66.15pt;" colspan="2" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin: 2.25pt 0in .0001pt 6.75pt;"><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: #2f2f2f; position: relative; top: -1pt;"><span style="letter-spacing: -.1pt;">SSN#:<br></span></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 4; mso-yfti-lastrow: yes; height: 66.15pt;">
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border-top: none; border-left: solid black 2.25pt; border-bottom: solid black 1.5pt; border-right: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 66.15pt;" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin: 2.25pt 0in .0001pt 8.25pt;"><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: #2f2f2f; position: relative; top: -1pt;"><span style="letter-spacing: -.1pt;">Date of Birth:<br><u>11/11/1111</u></span></span></p>
</td>
<td style="width: 641.9pt; border: none; border-right: solid black 1.5pt; border-bottom: solid black 1.5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid black 2.25pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid black 2.25pt; padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in; height: 66.15pt;" colspan="2" valign="top" width="856">
<p class="TableParagraph" style="margin: 2.25pt 0in .0001pt 6.75pt;"><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; color: #2f2f2f; position: relative; top: -1pt;"><span style="letter-spacing: -.1pt;">Date of Birth:<br></span></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I read and saw it was because of the table class but with I do not have experience coding and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not sure what you mean "export my table as a PDF document" - what specific software are you using to convert this to a PDF?